# Fetch with devise_token_auth in react-native

Tags: react-native, devise, rails-api

I'm new with react-native. I'm trying to satisfy the devise_token_auth requirement of send in every request the authetication headers. To do so, I'm trying something like this:

```
export const scheduleFetch = (auth) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(URL, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'access-token': auth['acessToken'],
        'token-type': auth['tokenType'],
        'client': auth['client'],
        'uid': auth['uid']
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      response.json()
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  }
}
```

My back-end is receiving the request, all headers are fill. However, I still receiving the message `"_bodyText":"{\"errors\":[\"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.\"]}"`.

How can I make that work? Am I jumping any step?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very late response, but in case someone else comes across looking for an answer, devise_token_auth changes the access token on each request by default (**change_headers_on_each_request** = true). Therefore, you need to not only send the auth token with each request, but you need to save the new auth token on each response. You can turn this off by setting it to false in the initializer settings in *config/initializers/devise_token_auth.rb*, in which case the access token won't change, though would be less secure.